# three dependent picker view

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c

I need to create three independent pickerView's. The first pickerView is categoryPickerView. When a value is selected it should load other 2 pickerView's (productPickerview and modelPickerview) are not loading the data correctly.

The didSelectRow callback is being fired but my NSLog's have shown that its not getting passed the first if statement checking if its equal to "Audio"

For catogeryPickerView I have written following array for it in viewDidLoad:-

```
 devicecatogery=[[NSArray alloc]initWithObjects:@"Audio",@"Video", nil];
//code for numeric keypad done button    
UIToolbar* numberToolbar = [[UIToolbar alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 44, 320, 300)];
numberToolbar.barStyle = UIBarStyleBlackTranslucent;
numberToolbar.items = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:
                       [[UIBarButtonItem alloc]initWithTitle:@"Cancel" style:UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered target:self action:@selector(cancelNumberPad)],
                       [[UIBarButtonItem alloc]initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemFlexibleSpace target:nil action:nil],
                       [[UIBarButtonItem alloc]initWithTitle:@"Apply" style:UIBarButtonItemStyleDone target:self action:@selector(doneWithNumberPad)],
                       nil];
[numberToolbar sizeToFit];


// catogery pickerview
categoryPickerView=[[UIPickerView alloc]init];
categoryPickerView.delegate=self;
categoryPickerView.tag=1;
txtCategory.inputView=categoryPickerView;
txtCategory.inputAccessoryView=numberToolbar;

//product pickerview
productPickerView=[[UIPickerView alloc]init];
productPickerView.delegate=self;
productPickerView.tag=2;
txtProduct.inputView=productPickerView;
txtProduct.inputAccessoryView=numberToolbar;

//model pickerview
modelPickerView=[[UIPickerView alloc]init];
modelPickerView.delegate=self;
modelPickerView.tag=3;
txtModel.inputView=modelPickerView;
txtModel.inputAccessoryView=numberToolbar;

}//end of view did load
```

this is my event for picker view:-

```
- (NSInteger)numberOfComponentsInPickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView{
    return 1;
}

 - (NSInteger)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView numberOfRowsInComponent:(NSInteger)component{
if (pickerView.tag == 1) {
    return [devicecatogery count];  //<-----------this is for category picker view
}else if(pickerView.tag == 2)
    return [commanProductArray count];     //<-----------this is for product picker view
else
    return [commanModelArray count];  //<-------------- this is for model picker view
}

- (NSString *)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView titleForRow:(NSInteger)row forComponent:(NSInteger)component
 {
if (pickerView.tag == 1)
    return [devicecatogery objectAtIndex:row];//<----this is for category picker view
else if (pickerView.tag == 2)
    return [commanProductArray objectAtIndex:row];//<--------this is for product picker view
else
    return [commanModelArray objectAtIndex:row];//<--------- this is for model picker view
}
```

Here is my didSelect callback:

```
  - (void)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView didSelectRow:(NSInteger)row inComponent:(NSInteger)component{

    if ([[categoryArray objectAtIndex:[categoryPickerView selectedRowInComponent:0] ]            isEqual:@"Audio"]) {

        commanProductArray=[[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithObjects:@"walkman",@"mp3",@"ipod", nil];

        if ([[commanProductArray objectAtIndex:[productPickerView selectedRowInComponent:0]] isEqual:@"walkman"]) {
            // walkman list display
            [productPickerView reloadAllComponents];

            commanModelArray=[[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithObjects:@"walkman1",@"walkman2",@"walkman3",@"walkman4", nil];
            [modelPickerView reloadAllComponents];
        }else if ([[commanProductArray objectAtIndex:[productPickerView selectedRowInComponent:0]] isEqual:@"mp3"]){

           //mp3 list display
            [productPickerView reloadAllComponents];
            [modelPickerView reloadAllComponents];

            commanModelArray=[[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithObjects:@"mp3",@"mp3",@"mp3",@"mp3", nil];
        }else if ([[commanProductArray objectAtIndex:[productPickerView selectedRowInComponent:0]] isEqual:@"ipod"]){
            //ipod list display
            [productPickerView reloadAllComponents];
            [modelPickerView reloadAllComponents];
            commanModelArray=[[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithObjects:@"ipod1",@"ipod2",@"ipod3",@"ipod4", nil];
        }        
    }else if ([[categoryArray objectAtIndex:[categoryPickerView selectedRowInComponent:0]] isEqual:@"Video"]){
        commanProductArray=[[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithObjects:@"TV",@"Moniter",@"Projector", nil];

        if ([[commanProductArray objectAtIndex:[productPickerView selectedRowInComponent:0]]isEqual:@"TV"])  {
            //for tv model display
            [productPickerView reloadAllComponents];
            commanModelArray=[[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithObjects:@"TV1",@"TV2",@"TV3", nil];
            [modelPickerView reloadAllComponents];

        }else if ([[commanProductArray objectAtIndex:[productPickerView  selectedRowInComponent:0]]isEqual:@"Moniter"]){
            //for moniter model display
            [productPickerView reloadAllComponents];
        commanModelArray=[[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithObjects:@"Moniter1",@"Moniter2",@"Moniter3", nil];
            [modelPickerView reloadAllComponents];

        }else if ([[commanProductArray objectAtIndex:[productPickerView selectedRowInComponent:0]] isEqual:@"Projector"]){
            //for projector display
            [productPickerView reloadAllComponents];
            commanModelArray=[[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithObjects:@"Projector1",@"Projector2",@"Projector3", nil];
            [modelPickerView reloadAllComponents];
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: please describe "not loading accordingly", anything displaying, controls are displaying but no data, callbacks not being called etc.

Comment: the other picker view are not loading (productPickerview and modelPickerview) is my code correct pls help @Dhaval Bhadania

Comment: the categoryPickerView is showing Audio and Video,but when Audio is selected the productPickerView is not showing walkman,mp3,ipod @Simon McLoughlin

Comment: @user2598751 please post more of your code, I can't understand how your trying to achieve this based on your code / comments. We need to see all the variables declared and all the callbacks.

Comment: i have edited my code for u @Simon McLoughlin

Comment: @user2598751 you said your productPickerView is not laoding, i still dont see any code that is attempting to load it. Calling "reloadAllComponents" doesn't make it magically work. Where is it being added, where is the data being passed in etc etc etc. Please post ALL of the necessary code

Comment: i have once more edited my code @Simon McLoughlin

Comment: if(pickerView.tag == 1) { } replace this with if(categoryPickerView == pickerView) { }if(pickerView.tag == 2) { } replace this with if(productPickerView == pickerView) { }if(pickerView.tag == 3) { } replace this with if(modelPickerView == pickerView) { }

Comment: 1 problem I see here is that you will have to create three different toolbars for each inputAccessoryView
2nd after you assign commanProductArray you will have to reload your picker, which you are not doing.

Comment: @user2598751 can you check my code one time or not ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code doesn't make sense to me, I suspect your issue is here:

```
- (void)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView didSelectRow:(NSInteger)row inComponent:(NSInteger)component{

    if ([[categoryArray objectAtIndex:[categoryPickerView selectedRowInComponent:0] ]            isEqual:@"Audio"]) {

        commanProductArray=[[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithObjects:@"walkman",@"mp3",@"ipod", nil];

        if ([[commanProductArray objectAtIndex:[productPickerView selectedRowInComponent:0]] isEqual:@"walkman"]) {
            // walkman list display
            [productPickerView reloadAllComponents];
```

All of the pickerView's are going into this callback when selected. You are first of all not checking the tags to see which pickerView it was that fired, then you check if the row selected is audio / video, if its the second / third pickers, the code will never get passed this as they will not have audio / video selected.

Following the logic, if "Audio" is selected you set `commanProductArray` to the given values, then you immediately check the selected value is equal to "walkman" before loading it.

`[productPickerView reloadAllComponents];` should be called directly after `commanProductArray` is set I suspect, as you set the array and check which value is selected before loading it.

This issue could have been spotted by simply putting 2 or 3 `NSlog`'s to see was it getting into the loop

**EDIT:**

Your code should follow something more like this:

```
- (void)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView didSelectRow:(NSInteger)row inComponent:(NSInteger)component
{
    // If first picker
    if(pickerView.tag == 1)
    {
        // If Audio
        if(row == 0)
        {
            // Load result for audio
        }
        // If Video
        else if (row == 1)
        {
            // load result for video
        }
    }
    // If second picker
    else if(pickerView.tag == 2)
    {
        // if Walkman
        if(row == 0)
        {
            // load result for walkman
        }

        // etc etc etc
    }
    else if (pickerView.tag == 3)
    {

    }
}
```

Comment: i tried useing NSLog but it is not comming in loop after                     'if ([[categoryArray objectAtIndex:[categoryPickerView selectedRowInComponent:0] ]            isEqual:@"Audio"]) {
NSLog(@"1");'          @Simon McLoughlin

Comment: @user2598751 ... so you found that NSlog's weren't printing meaning your if statement wasn't working, meaning you identified the issue and didn't mention this in the question why? Why do you even need to string compare, why not just check the index: if(pickerView.tag == 1 && row == 0) //Row 0 will be equal to audio

Comment: @user2598751 just noticed this:   ' isEqual:@"Audio"] '   is not doing a string compare, it should have been ' isEqualToString:@"Audio"] '

Comment: i did according to but now it is not going to third loop i.e loading of modelpickerview.it is not loading array of model @Simon McLoughlin

Comment: @user2598751 I walked through your code in my answer and pointed out that the structure of what you are doing is wrong. I have edited my answer to show you how it should look. You need to read my code comments and follow the flow, your not getting what I'm saying as your not trying to understand the difference, you are just looking for a handout for someone to give you the code to make it work, as evidence it seems like you just copied the code I gave, not noticing it only fixed one if statement

Comment: thanks @Simon McLoughlin  your solution worked but the values of other  picker views are changing ....i am displaying picker values using NSLog

Comment: @user2598751 Im sorry I dont understand what you mean, please edit your question, add the code ur using now and explain your issue in full, and the result of any NSLog's

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/44414/discussion-between-user2598751-and-simon-mcloughlin)

Answer (score 0):

Try this one:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    devicecatogery=[[NSArray alloc]initWithObjects:@"Audio",@"Video", nil];
    commanProductArray=[[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithObjects:@"walkman",@"mp3",@"ipod", nil];
    commanModelArray=[[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithObjects:@"walkman1",@"walkman2",@"walkman3",@"walkman4", nil];
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view from its nib.
}


// tell the picker how many rows are available for a given component
- (NSInteger)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView numberOfRowsInComponent:(NSInteger)component {

    if (pickerView.tag==1) {
         return devicecatogery.count;
    }
    else if(pickerView.tag==2){
        return commanProductArray.count;
    }
    else if (pickerView.tag==3)
    {
        return commanModelArray.count;

    }
    return 0;
}

// tell the picker how many components it will have
- (NSInteger)numberOfComponentsInPickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView {
    return 1;
}

// tell the picker the title for a given component
- (NSString *)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView titleForRow:(NSInteger)row forComponent:(NSInteger)component
{
    NSString *title;
    if (pickerView.tag==1)
    {
        title = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[devicecatogery objectAtIndex:row]];
    }
    else if (pickerView.tag==2)
    {
        if([categoryPickerView selectedRowInComponent:0]==0)
        {
            commanProductArray=[[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithObjects:@"walkman",@"mp3",@"ipod", nil];
        }
        else{
            commanProductArray=[[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithObjects:@"TV",@"Moniter",@"Projector", nil];
        }
        title = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[commanProductArray objectAtIndex:row]];
    }
    else if (pickerView.tag==3)
    {
          if ([[devicecatogery objectAtIndex:[categoryPickerView selectedRowInComponent:0]] isEqualToString:@"Audio"]) {

              if([productPickerview selectedRowInComponent:0]==0)
              {
                  commanModelArray=[[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithObjects:@"walkman1",@"walkman2",@"walkman3",@"walkman4", nil];

              }
              else if([productPickerview selectedRowInComponent:0]==1)
              {
                  commanModelArray=[[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithObjects:@"mp31",@"mp32",@"mp33",@"mp34", nil];

              }
              else if([productPickerview selectedRowInComponent:0]==2)
              {
                  commanModelArray=[[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithObjects:@"ipod1",@"ipod2",@"ipod3",@"ipod4", nil];
              }

          }
          else
          {
              if([productPickerview selectedRowInComponent:0]==0)
              {
                  commanModelArray=[[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithObjects:@"TV1",@"TV2",@"TV3",@"TV4", nil];
              }
              else if([productPickerview selectedRowInComponent:0]==1)
              {
                  commanModelArray=[[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithObjects:@"Moniter1",@"Moniter2",@"Moniter3",@"Moniter4", nil];
              }
              else if([productPickerview selectedRowInComponent:0]==2)
              {
                  commanModelArray=[[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithObjects:@"Projector1",@"Projector2",@"Projector3",@"Projector4", nil];
              }

          }
        title = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[commanModelArray objectAtIndex:row]];
    }
    return title;
}
- (void)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView didSelectRow:(NSInteger)row inComponent:(NSInteger)component{
    if (pickerView.tag==1)
    {
        [productPickerview reloadAllComponents];
        [modelPickerview reloadAllComponents];
    }
    if (pickerView.tag==2) {
        [modelPickerview reloadAllComponents];
    }
    // Handle the selection

}
```

For more detail you have to check it : [Sample code](http://ge.tt/2fM748C1/v/0)

May it will help you.

Happy coding...:)